# How do I insert a tag in front of equations as well as having the equations numbers in LaTeX?

Tags: equations

As the equation states, I would like to add a symbol tag in front of equations as well as having equations numbered.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Looks like duplicate of [How do you label an equation with something on the left and on the right? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/574791/how-do-you-label-an-equation-with-something-on-the-left-and-on-the-right) ; but the "symbol" part may mean something like a • or a ★ on the left side.

Comment: I would like to have a tag on the left of the equation as well as the equation number on the right of the equation.